# How to change the separators for Cakephp Form Helper for multiple checkboxes

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I'm generating a bunch of checkboxes through the Form Helper.
Essenciatially I have an array with like $tests = array

```
$tests = array(1 => 'test', 15=>'test2');
```

Then I can use it like this

```
echo $this->Form->input('test_id', array(
            'type' => 'select', 
            'multiple' => 'checkbox', 
            'div' => false,
            'before' => '<li>',
            'after' => '</li>',
            'separator' => '</li> <li>'));
```

I expected it would use the div => false to take off the div of every checkbox but it only applies the options to the exterior block. Is there anyway to change all the blocks from `<div class=>'checkbox'>` to `<li class='anything else'>`

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the fields it produces, then write your own simple `foreach()` loop and write them yourself in whatever wrapping element(s) you want.

I forget whether it's possible with Cake or not, but don't think it is.  The above is what we've done before - because it's simple to write, it took us less time to write than it did to look further into it :)